# Why is declaring a static array as a pointer causing this data abort?

Tags: c, arm

I'm using an Cortex-A9 chip (ZYNQ 7000) to store incoming network data to a static array in the RAM. I find that if I declare the array as a pointer in the source file that copies data, then a data abort error will happen during copying. In my several trials, `recvLen` is always 196172 when the data abort happens. Declaring the array as an array works properly. I know conflicting variable declaration and definition is bad, but I'm curious why it doesn't work in this case. The compiler is arm-none-eabi-gcc.

```c
// data.c
char dataBuffer[16777216];
```

```c
// network.c
#include <string.h>

extern char *dataBuffer; // cause data abort error
// extern char dataBuffer[16777216]; // works properly

int recvLen = 0;

int IsLengthValid(int recvLen, int len);

void OnReceivingData(const char *data, int len){
    if(IsLengthValid(recvLen,len)){
        memcpy(&dataBuffer[recvLen],data,len);
        recvLen += len;
    }
}
```

Comment: The best way to understand this is to look at the assembly code. Use `-S` to request the assembly from gcc, or look at the assembly with a debugger.

Comment: An array is not a pointer. That's all there is to it.

Comment: part from them being different types you should avoid using global variables for exchanging data. instead just pass the dataBuffer as an argument to all functions that access it, it makes the code clearer too. having a program which has different parts accessing a global variable is not a good design.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your program is ill-formed when you deceive the compiler when you say that `dataBuffer` is pointer `extern char *dataBuffer;` but it's actually an array `char dataBuffer[16777216];`.  On my system, it interprets the first `sizeof(char *) == 8 bytes` of the array as an address.  I think it comes down to 6.7.6.2, 6:

> For two array types to be compatible, both shall have compatible element types, and if both size
> specifiers are present, and are integer constant expressions, then both size specifiers shall have
> the same constant value. If the two array types are used in a context which requires them to be
> compatible, it is undefined behavior if the two size specifiers evaluate to unequal values.

If you don't want to repeat the size you can use an incomplete type (this is what goes into your data.h file; and original definition in your data.c file):

```
// data.h
extern char dataBuffer[];
```

```
// network.c
#include <data.h>
```

Or you can use a pointer in both files along these lines:

```
// data.c
char *dataBuffer = (char [16777216]) {0};
```

```
// network.c
extern char *dataBuffer;
```

Comment: `extern char dataBuffer[];` and leaving `char dataBuffer[16777216];` as it is looks cleaner to me.

Answer (score 1):

> Why is declaring a static array as a pointer causing this data abort?

Because on the pointer side, it is interpreting the *content* of the static array as a pointer *value*. Because the static array is statically initialized, it is initialized to zero. The first 4 bytes of the static array are zero, so the pointer is read as if it would have all bytes set to zero. Such a pointer is equal to zero, it is a null pointer. So dereferencing it is dereferencing a null pointer, causing the abort.

On the fundamental level, you broke the rules of the language, as the type of `dataBuffer` is not the same in both files.

You can test it. Try `dataBuffer[16777216] = {1,2,3,4}` and see what happens.

```
// data.c
char dataBuffer[16777216];
// main.c
#include <stdio.h>
extern char *dataBuffer;
int main() {
    printf("%p\n", (void*)dataBuffer);
}

$ arm-none-eabi-gcc main.c data.c --specs=rdimon.specs && qemu-arm ./a.out
0x0
```

Comment: Just curious what do you have in rdimon.specs?

Comment: I have https://github.com/bminor/newlib/blob/master/libgloss/arm/elf-rdimon.specs